# C++ Check if pointer is passed, else create one?

Tags: c++, pointers

Okay i've seen this done somewhere before where you have a function that takes a pointer parameter and returns a pointer.

However you can choose not to pass a parameter and it will return a dynamically allocated pointer but if you do pass a pointer then it just fills it in instead of creating one on the heap. This is a single function not overloaded.

My question is how is this safely done?

I had a guess it was something like this:

```
point* funct(point *p = some_value)
{
 if p == some_value
   //create a point *p on the heap

 else
   //create use the given *p and fill it in

 return p
}
```

Now i can't think if this is right way to do it and if it is then what could be a good some_value? it can't be NULL because when you pass empty pointer it will also be NULL and not sure if it is safe to have it greater than 0. Also you can't have negative numbers on pointers either, so whats a good safe value?

Any good way to do this that is also PORTABLE across platforms?

EDIT:

Okay maybe i didn't explain properly basically i want the function to be used like this:

```
point *x;
point *y;

x = func();
func(y);
```

Not

```
x = func(NULL);
```

if I use NULL i get an error segmentation fault only when i do func(y);

The reason for this is:

either the user passes a pointer he manages such as one created on the stack OR the function will give a dynamic one back if none is given. I don't want to force the return of only dynamic memory or only accepting a pointer to fill.

I know I have seen this done somewhere before.

Comment: Passing an empty pointer is not the same thing as passing NULL.

Comment: Not even sure what an "empty pointer" means :)

Comment: you can pass a NULL pointer to a function, you just cannot dereference it.

Comment: Unrelated to the answer: this is a bad design. Who is going to free the allocated point? Why would the caller not have a point to pass? { point p; funct(&p); } is better than { point* p = NULL; p = funct(NULL); delete p; }

Comment: I would assume an empty pointer points somewhere valid in memory with at least sizeof(point) bytes usable

Comment: In general, I would avoid this approach as it isn't make it clear who owns the memory that is allocated, which invites either memory leaks or an attempt to free stack memory.

Comment: I have edited my question to sort of make it more clear

Comment: In your new example, there is no way to use `func(y)` sanely. It isn't even legal to **compare** an uninitialized pointer to something.

Comment: It might not be the right way but somewhere I think in the linux libraries there was a function that works exactly like above not sure how it is allocated internally though

Comment: Just because you've seen it before doesn't mean it is a good idiom. If the user want to allocate it on the stack or heap make him responsible for doing that. Unless you are writing a heap manager it is not your function's job to facilitate heap allocation. Force the programmer to decide to allocate on the heap before calling your function so he doesn't forget to deallocate from the heap after he calls your function.

Comment: Several (libc even!) libraries return a pointer to a non thread safe static buffer when NULL is passed. Is this perhaps what you mean?

Comment: And if you are worried about receiving a null pointer, assert it. Or throw an exception on a null pointer.

Comment: I'm completely lost in what this question actually wants to do. Anyone understands?

Comment: Taking the advice I will let the user handle allocation. Where I have seen i'm not sure but it was from a linux/unix system library I think. Basically what I demonstrated above with func(y) with uninitialized pointer, thats exactly what it did, returns a pointer if nothing passed else it fills the passed pointer.

Comment: Perhaps in the example you remember y was a global variable. Global variables are initialized to 0 when the program starts.

Comment: @iQ: are you sure it didn't require an "empty" pointer to be NULL?

Comment: No it wasn't global, I created it inside a function, was a while ago when I used it, if I do remember where I saw it then I will post it :p

Comment: sounds like perhaps you had a bug which simply didn't show up during runtime because of luck. There is no legal way to do what you ask. Simply because there is no way to legally test if a pointer is uninitialized. That is what NULL is for. It is the value you use when you have nothing to point to.

Comment: This kind of code is so bad that there is a reference to it (to not do it) in Effective C++.  Take an address or return by value, asking the caller to deallocate the memory is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Most probably the default value was 0 / NULL. The segmentation fault you are getting probably has nothing to do with the default value, but rather with the fact that you are passing an uninitialized (random) value.

Comment: well technically, most OSs do have a way to distinguish amongst "empty" and invalid pointers. Things like PointerIsValid or something I don't remember, but I remember seeing it in Windows API and in OpenBSD's.. oh and I think the Linux driver API

Comment: No, no OS has such possibilities. If the pointer randomly points to another object in your address space, it's still "empty", but the OS would say it's not.

Comment: PointerIsValid only tests if the pointer points outside your address space. If it points within your address space to non-heap data, you will corrupt something if you access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask yourself why passing NULL us giving you a seg-fault. It is certainly not because NULL is not an appropriate value, it will be caused by whatever your code does when NULL is passed. However you chose not to show that code.

Haver you stepped through this code in your debugger?

Apart from that, in C++ *do not* use NULL. It is a macro and open to incorrect redefinition. Use plain zero (0). The language places guarantees that a zero literal constant when converted to a pointer will not be a valid address. The chances are that your NULL macro is in fact defined as zero.

If you attempt to dereference a null pointer you will get a fault.

Comment: I did indeed have 0 at the beginning and it was working alright I think (if i remember right) but I thought NULL maybe a better portable solution. If however if the language guarantees 0 will not be valid then I may stick to it. Though now i've decided to follow a similiar idiom to ctime with the time() function

Comment: better yet, use null_ptr - a new keyword.

Answer (score 8):

Normal solution is to have 'if NULL allocate' - that's what 'c' realloc does.

It looks like you want to have a function that uses existing memory if provided or else allocates it's own.
It's not clear what you should return if you are passed a valid pointer.
Should it return that pointer?
Or should it be null to ensure that there aren't two copies of pointers to the same bit of memory - which will cause problems if they are freed.

It might be safer to pass a **pointer into the function and require an argument - even if that arguement is a pointer to null.

Comment: actually thats exactly what I want to do but not with local pointer but allocate a new pointer and return that

Answer (score 3):

Well obviously if a someone ever was to call funct(NULL) then it would result in a crash anyway. so why not have some_value=NULL so to make

```
if(p==NULL){
  p=dynamic_memory;
}
```

where dynamic_memory is allocated in the constructor(not thread-safe!) or replace dynamic_memory with a call to new

Edit:

Or. If you must have 3 states in your function, one for if no argument is supplied, one for if a valid pointer is passed, and one for if NULL is passed, then you can use pointer-to-pointers.

like

```
void *func(void** p=NULL){
  if(p==NULL) ...//user supplied no argument
  if(*p==NULL) ...//user supplied NULL
  else //user supplied valid pointer
```

This doesn't seem to be what you want however and then people would have to pass pointers with '&' to your function.. (is `&NULL` even valid?)

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be more along the lines of:

```
point* funct(point *p = NULL)
{
    if (p == NULL) {
        // create a point *p on the heap
        // and use it
        return(p);
    }
    else {
        //use the given *p and fill it in
        return(NULL);
    }
 }
```

Not too sure about having the possibility of the pointer to your point object passed in though. Could be quite hard to check for, and checking the type of an object passed in, i.e. "looking under the covers" using RTTI, is not the best OO practice.

Comment: yeah but you should also replace some_value with NULL, e.g., "point* funct(point *p = NULL)"

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
T* func(T* p) {
    if(!p) {
        p = new T;
    }
    // do whatever with p
    return p;
}
```

then you can either do:

```
T* x = func(NULL);
// whatever
delete x;
```

or:

```
T x;
func(&x);
```

**EDIT:**

There is a **non-thread safe** option which several libraries use. Basically it works like this:

```
T* func(T* p) {
    static T buf;
    if(!p) {
        p = buf;
    }
    // do whatever with p
    return p;
}
```

then you can either do:

```
T* p = func(NULL);
```

or:

```
T x;
T* p = func(&x);
```

There are often "reentrant" versions of these as well which are  often tied to the non-thread safe versions like this:

```
T* func(T* p) {
    // behaves as above example, except now we can
    // use func_r in a thread safe way if we need to
    static T buf;
    return func_r(p, buf);
}

T* func_r(T* p, T *buf) {
    if(!p) {
        p = buf;
    }
    // do whatever with p
    return p;
}
```

Comment: `!p` is not valid, as NULL is not always defined as 0.

Comment: @earlz: incorrect, in c++ NULL *is* 0. 0 is the null pointer constant. See the standard section 4.10.

Comment: to quote that section: A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to
zero. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that
type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or pointer to function type."

Note: there is a difference between the "null pointer constant" and the "null pointer value"

Comment: I've made some edits on the question it should make things clear, but I'm trying to avoid that way

Comment: NULL pet-peeve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/1331729#1331729

Comment: @litb: seems we keep encountering people who confuse this issue over and over again :-(.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error when you call func(y) because y is not initialized. It contains random bits that point to a random location in memory. You need to initialize y to NULL.

```
 point *x, *y;

 x = func();
 y = NULL;
 y = func(y); // so it can be deleted later you need to assign the return value
 delete x;
 delete y;
```

Why not do this? And avoid the heap allocation completely.

```
 point x, y;
 func(&x);
 func(&y);
```

Or:

```
 point *x;
 point *y = new point();
 x = func();
 func(y);
 delete x;
 delete y;
```

As I said in the comment above, memory ownership is confusing in your function. Functions that dynamically allocate their results should do so every time or none of the time. When they do so some of the time, the potential for a memory leak is much higher.

Personally, I would go even further and avoid all allocations, pass by reference:

```
 void func(point& p)
 {
      //do stuff
 }

 point x, y;
 func(x);
 func(y);
```

Comment: I think that I will probably do, pass by reference possibly safest.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it NULL (have null be default...) if you want to allocate, and pass an empty pointer if you want to fill in.

As jeffamaphone commented, there is a difference between an empty pointer and NULL, use your conditional statements to check if it is an empty pointer or NULL

Comment: how do you tell the difference from an empty pointer and a "filled" pointer though?

Comment: what exactly is an empty pointer? don't pointers get defaulted to NULL when nothing is assigned?

Comment: iQ: NO. Local variables are uninitialized unless you initialize them.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with using NULL?  That's the general way this is handled.  If you *really* need to distinguish between "caller passed nothing" and "caller passed NULL", then use `0xFFFFFFFF` on a 32-bit system or `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` on a 64-bit system.

```
point * funct(point * p = (point *)(-1))
{
    if (p == (point *)(-1))
    {
        p = new point();
    }

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        // special case handling
        return NULL;
    }

    // fill in p
    return p
}
```

The '-1' cast will always be the maximum pointer value as long as you are on a two's-compliment architecture.  Feel free to substitute the C-style cast with a reinterpret cast if you prefer.

Comment: There are architectures where the (point*)(-1) cast will cause a fault. This is not portable code. If you REALLY need to distinguish between NULL and some other non-pointer value, create a second parameter with a bool or enum type.

Comment: yeah initially I had the -1 idea but it seems to be unfriendly, not sure if I should take the risk

Comment: On what architecture will casting -1 to a pointer cause a fault?  Attempting to use such a pointer would obviously cause a fault, but I see no reason that creating the pointer would be problematic.

Comment: @Derek:  I'm not sure on what architectures this will be a problem, but there may well be some.  I'm not keen on advocating undefined behavior on the basis that it happens to work on all the machines I'm currently familiar with.

Comment: I have trouble envisioning a practical architecture on which this is a problem.  This being a problem implies that the system is checking for the validity of the pointer, which is an expensive operation (given that it has to ask the OS if it's valid) with no real benefit that I can see.  I can't see this kind of platform being compatible with the C++ virtual machine, since C++ uses invalid pointers (one past the end) to mark the ends of arrays and containers.

Answer (score 1):

> However you can choose not to pass a parameter and it will return a dynamically allocated pointer but if you do pass a pointer then it just fills it in instead of creating one on the heap. This is a single function not overloaded.

Instead of using default arguments, you could overload the function:

```
point* funct(point *p = some_value)
{
    // fills p
}

point* funct()
{
    return funct(new point());
}
```

> It might not be the right way but somewhere I think in the linux libraries there was a function that works exactly like above not sure how it is allocated internally though

I'm not aware of any such function.  I would guess you're thinking of [realloc](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/realloc.html) which takes a pointer and a `size_t` and then decides whether to allocate memory, adjust already allocated memory, or free memory.

> Now i can't think if this is right way to do it and if it is then what could be a good some_value? it can't be NULL because when you pass empty pointer it will also be NULL and not sure if it is safe to have it greater than 0. Also you can't have negative numbers on pointers either, so whats a good safe value?

I think your confusion comes from a fundamental misunderstanding of the `NULL` pointer.

Observe:

```
int x = 5;
int* px = &x;
int* p_null = NULL;
int* p;
int* p_new = new int();
```

`px` points to x, so it's not `NULL`.  `p_null` begins life as `NULL` which means it doesn't point to anything.

I think you're using the term "empty pointer" to refer to something like `p` or `p_new`.  However, although `p` doesn't point to a valid object it wasn't set to `NULL` either.  It's effectively an invalid pointer, and there is no portable way to tell that it's invalid (on some machines it [may be possible to tell if something is obviously not valid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902%28VS.85%29.aspx), but even then it's not possible to catch all invalid pointers -- *see note* -- and [you probably don't want to anyway](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx) -- second half).

And `p_new` points to a valid address in dynamic memory.  It's not NULL.  It's not empty.  In fact, `new` will initialize the `int` to 0.

In other words, `NULL` is the value you pass to functions that expect a pointer to tell them you don't have a pointer.  That's what it is.  And there isn't really the idea of an empty pointer.  Dangling pointers (either uninitialized pointers, or pointers to memory that you don't have access to) aren't `NULL`, because if they were `NULL` they wouldn't dangle.  And it's impossible to validate pointers in all cases to determine if they are valid.

---

**NOTE**

Consider:

```
int* p_new2 = new int();
delete p_new2;
```

`delete` does not set `p_new2` to `NULL`.  So after the `delete`, `p_new2` will have an address in the correct range for a valid pointer (meaning that Windows' VirtualQuery method will say "sure, a pointer could point there"), but will not have permission to actually dereference that memory address.

**NOTE 2**

This is a terribly bad idea, don't do it:

```
int* funct()
{
    int y = 5;
    return &y;
}

int* x = funct();
```

`y` ceases to exist after `funct()` returns.  So the the pointer to `y` that `funct()` hands you points to something that doesn't exist.  So you get a dangling pointer.  You're not talking about doing this, but it's a common mistake, and it will bite you.

Answer (score 0):

Default value is what it is — default value. There's no such thing like *not* passing value here. It may only happen with variable parameters count, but that's different story.

And what is an "empty pointer"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
point* funct(point *p = some_value)
{
 if (p == NULL)
   return NULL;

 if (p == some_value) 
   p = new point;

   return p;
}
```

Comment: the problem is if only i know what would be a nice some_value

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've decided not to use that idiom seems bad although I know one of the unix or linux system libraries had a function like that.

I'm not answering my own question but I just remembered the ctime idiom which is probably a much safer way to do what I want. I'm talking about the time() function.

Where it takes a pointer or returns a object by value.

I think it probably even gives better flexibility of returning by value, heap or stack allocation with pointer thats user controlled. I don't know why I didn't think of this before.

What do you guys thing, the ctime idiom is much better right?

Edit: Does that idiom use NULL check?

Comment: It would be best to ask this as a separate question.  Otherwise this question will have a large number of answers to your original question, and another group of answers to the new one.  That won't be easy to piece through.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to split them in such a way you can't accidentally provide the default function, you ought ot overload the functions.

```
point* funct() {
    //alocate a point* p here
    return funct(p);
}
```

and

```
point* funct(point *p) {
    //do stuff
}
```